# Grep does not show results, online regex tester does

Tags: regex, grep

I am fairly unexperienced with the behavior of grep. I have a bunch of XML files that contain lines like these:

```
<identifier type="abc">abc:def.ghi/g1234.ab012345</identifier>
<identifier type="abc">abc:def.ghi/g5678m.ab678901</identifier>
```

I wanted to get the identifier part after the slash and constructed a regex using [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/):

```
[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*
```

It highlights everything that I wanted. Perfect. Now when I run grep on the very same file, I don't get any results. And as I said, I really don't know much about grep, so I tried all different combinations.

```
grep [a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d* test.xml
grep "[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*" test.xml
egrep "[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*" test.xml
grep '[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*' test.xml
grep -E '[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*' test.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match the input.  Let's break it down:

- `[a-z]` matches `g`
- `\d{4}` matches `1234`
- `[a-z]*` doesn't match `.`

Also, I believe `grep` and family don't like the `\d` syntax.  Try either `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`

Finally, when using regular expressions, prefer `egrep` to `grep`.  I don't remember the exact details, but `egrep` supports more regex operators.  Also, in many shells (including bash on OS X as you mentioned, use single quotes instead of double quotes, otherwise `*` will be expanded by the shell to a list of files in the current directory before grep sees it (and other shell meta-characters will get expanded too).  Bash won't touch anything in single quotes.

Comment: Had a typo there, sorry. It's corrected now. And the regex still matches in the online tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `egrep` rocks.

Comment: I'm confused.  `[a-z]*` doesn't match `.` but it is optional so it matches 0 characters and then the next bit of the regex does match the dot.  And that's why it works on the regex tester site.  I think the actual problem is using extended regex like you suggested.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` doesn't support `\d` by defaul. To match a digit, use `[0-9]`, or allow Perl compatible regular expressions:

```
$ grep -P "[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*" test.xml
```

or:

```
$ egrep "[a-z][0-9]{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*[0-9]*" test.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

grep uses "basic" regular expressions : (excerpt from man pages )

```
Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
   In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their
   special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{,  \|,  \(,  and
   \).

   Traditional  egrep  did  not  support  the  {  meta-character,  and  some  egrep
   implementations support \{ instead,  so  portable  scripts  should  avoid  {  in
   grep -E patterns and should use [{] to match a literal {.

   GNU  grep -E  attempts  to  support  traditional usage by assuming that { is not
   special if it would be the start of  an  invalid  interval  specification.   For
   example,  the  command  grep -E '{1'  searches  for  the two-character string {1
   instead of reporting a syntax error in the regular expression.   POSIX.2  allows
   this behavior as an extension, but portable scripts should avoid it.
```

Also depending on which shell you are executing in the '*' character might get expanded.

Comment: I'm using bash 3.2 on OS X. The -E switch doesn't help, either (added it in my original question)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the following command:

```
$ cat file
<identifier type="abc">abc:def.ghi/g1234.ab012345</identifier>

# Use -P option to enable Perl style regex \d.
$ grep -P  '[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*' file
<identifier type="abc">abc:def.ghi/g1234.ab012345</identifier>

# to get only the part of the input that matches use -o option:
$ grep -P -o '[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*' file
g1234.ab012345

# You can use [0-9] inplace of \d and use -E option.
$ grep -E -o '[a-z][0-9]{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*[0-9]*' file
g1234.ab012345
$
```

Comment: Sorry, i had a typo there. The test file is right, and the regex matches in the online tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[a-z]\d{5}[.][a-z]{2}\d{6}

Comment: OK, changing requirements, then do try this: [a-z][0-9]{4}[1-z]*[.][a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression in grep:

```
[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\d*
```